# How do I create a dictionary mapping strings to sets given a list and a tuple of tuples?

Tags: list, dictionary, tuples, python

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list and tuple of tuples as illustrated below. I have to reverse map the tuples to the list and create a set of non-None column names.

Any suggestions on a pythonic way to achieve the solution (desired dictionary) is much appreciated.

**MySQL table 'StateLog':**

```
Name NY   TX   NJ
Amy  1    None 1
Kat  None 1    1
Leo  None None 1
```

**Python code :**

```
## Fetching data from MySQL table
#cursor.execute("select * from statelog")
#mydataset = cursor.fetchall()
## Fetching column names for mapping
#state_cols = [fieldname[0] for fieldname in cursor.description]

state_cols = ['Name', 'NY', 'TX', 'NJ']
mydataset = (('Amy', '1', None, '1'), ('Kat', None, '1', '1'), ('Leo', None, None, '1'))

temp = [zip(state_cols, each) for each in mydataset]

# Looks like I can't do a tuple comprehension for the following snippet : finallist = ((eachone[1], eachone[0]) for each in temp for eachone in each if eachone[1] if eachone[0] == 'Name')
for each in temp:
    for eachone in each:
        if eachone[1]:
            if eachone[0] == 'Name':
                k = eachone[1]
            print k, eachone[0]

print '''How do I get a dictionary in this format'''            
print '''name_state = {"Amy": set(["NY", "NJ"]),
                "Kat": set(["TX", "NJ"]),
                "Leo": set(["NJ"])}'''
```

**Output so far :**

```
Amy Name
Amy NY
Amy NJ
Kat Name
Kat TX
Kat NJ
Leo Name
Leo NJ
```

**Desired dictionary :**

```
name_state = {"Amy": set(["NY", "NJ"]),
              "Kat": set(["TX", "NJ"]),
              "Leo": set(["NJ"])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be really honest, I would say your problem is that your code is becoming too cumbersome. Resist the temptation of "one-lining" it and create a function. Everything will become way easier!

```
mydataset = (
        ('Amy', '1', None, '1'),
        ('Kat', None, '1', '1'),
        ('Leo', None, None, '1')
)

def states(cols, data):
    """
    This function receives one of the tuples with data and returns a pair
    where the first element is the name from the tuple, and the second
    element is a set with all matched states. Well, at least *I* think
    it is more readable :)
    """
    name = data[0]
    states = set(state for state, value in zip(cols, data) if value == '1')
    return name, states

pairs = (states(state_cols, data) for data in mydataset)
# Since dicts can receive an iterator which yields pairs where the first one
# will become a key and the second one will become the value, I just pass
# a list with all pairs to the dict constructor.
print dict(pairs)
```

The result is:

```
{'Amy': set(['NY', 'NJ']), 'Leo': set(['NJ']), 'Kat': set(['NJ', 'TX'])}
```

Comment: I was playing with it at command line, did not get to the functions part. I just wanted to make it work with sample sets and then structure it. It works great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ThinkCode sorry, I was not aware you are a neophyte :) Anyway, you can expand the function inside de list comprehensions,  but this will become HUGE!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like another job for [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)!

So lets create our default dict

```
name_state = collections.defaultdict(set)
```

We now have a dictionary that has sets as all default values, we can now do something like this

```
name_state['Amy'].add('NY')
```

Moving on you just need to iterate over your object and add to each name the right states. Enjoy

Comment: I will look into defaultdict, Python is full of features and surprises I see!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a dictionary comprehension (Python 2.7+):

```
from itertools import compress
name_state = {data[0]: set(compress(state_cols[1:], data[1:])) for data in mydataset}
```

or as a generator expression:

```
name_state = dict((data[0], set(compress(state_cols[1:], data[1:]))) for data in mydataset)
```

Comment: It is showing a syntax error at 'for'. I never did something like this for a dictionary, looks cool!

Comment: @ThinkCode: What version of python are you using? Dict comprehensions only work for 2.7+. I am editing to include a generator expression version that should work for 2.3+.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6.6. Thanks for the answer, I will check it out.